# InfoPath 2010 forms do not open in the Browser using IE8

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

If the user has InfoPath installed on their PC the form will default to open in InfoPath. This is not desirable. All forms should open in the browser not in InfoPath. Why? Because some users in the company my have infopath installed and some may not. It's unrealistic to uninstall InfoPath on users computers just so the forms will open in the browser.

Please review this video for more details: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkIeE8MTnSc

Comment: This is a superuser issue I think as it's do with what program is used to open an an xml document.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean Preet. Can you explain further?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. For me, pasting "?OpenIn=Browser" after the links (by default), solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can force Sharepoint to open Infopath forms in the browser instead of the client application (Infopath).

In short:

1. Make sure your form is browser enabled
2. Make sure your form library is set to "Display as web page" under advanced settings
3. Make sure you configure the InfoPath Forms Services to render form templates that are browser enabled by users.

Quote from [Open Infopath form in a browser when click New Item on Forms Library](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/sharepointinfopath/thread/68122772-A20C-40F0-8193-B2C48331E68B):

> When you are creating a Infopath form make sure you tick the Enable
>   browser enabled features only at the time when you are creating a new
>   infopath form. Make sure that your form is browser enabled (Tools ->
>   Form Options -> Compatibility) in InfoPath. The "Design a form that
>   can be opened in the browser" is checked and selected. After designing
>   your form publish it in your Sharepoint Forms Library.
>
> After that follow this step:
>
> - Go to the Form Library to which you published the InfoPath form
>     template.
> - Click Settings on the Form Library menu bar and choose Form
>     Library Settings from the drop-down menu.
> - On the Customize  page under the General
>     Settings category, click Advanced settings .
> - On the Form Library Advanced Settings:  page
>     under the Browser-enabled Documents category, choose Display as a Web
>     page .
>
> From the Central Administration also make sure to enable this feature.
>
> To enable this setting:
>
> - Open SharePoint Central Administration .
> - Click the Application Management tab.
> - On the Application Management page under the InfoPath Forms
>     Services category, click Configure InfoPath Forms Services .
> - On the Configure InfoPath Forms Services page under the User
>     Browser-enabled Form Templates category, check Render form templates
>     that are browser-enabled by users .

Comment: moontear, did you review the youtube video? I followed your above instructions to the letter and it still will not work.

Comment: I have to admit, I didn't watch it to the end where you show your correct settings in Central Administration. From your original post it isn't clear and the video is quite info laden: What is your expected behavior? **Open all forms in the browser, regardless of Infopath being installed or not?** And also when you open Infopath forms via Outlook it shall work? Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Hey @DennisG I have followed all of these instructions and still having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

InfoPath will not open in Browser when used as a default form in a 2010 SharePoint Document set.  This occurs whether force open in browser is set or not.  It's a bug.  I am wondering  what InfoPath sees when it determines whether or not to open in the client and if there is a way to disable this writing some custom code into the form?  Or perhaps once could customize the document set settings such that it would always open in the browser?  from other posts on the web this problem also occurs with various other SharePoint 2010 special libraries/templates such as record center.

Answer (score 0):

Moontear, The expected behavior is that ALL links (search links, task links, workflow email links) associated with the published InfoPath form open in the browser regardless of InfoPath being installed on users PCs. Keep in mind that ALL form links will open in the browser when using Chrome or FireFox.